# Get total of Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a Pandas data frame, as shown below, with multiple columns and would like to get the total of column, `MyColumn`.

```
           X           MyColumn      Y              Z   
0          A           84         13.0           69.0   
1          B           76         77.0          127.0   
2          C           28         69.0           16.0   
3          D           28         28.0           31.0   
4          E           19         20.0           85.0   
5          F           84        193.0           70.0
```

---

***Expected Output***

I'd have expected the output to be the total of this column: `319`.

Or alternatively, I would like `df` to be edited with a new row entitled `TOTAL` containing the total:

```
           X           MyColumn      Y              Z   
0          A           84         13.0           69.0   
1          B           76         77.0          127.0   
2          C           28         69.0           16.0   
3          D           28         28.0           31.0   
4          E           19         20.0           85.0   
5          F           84        193.0           70.0   
TOTAL                  319
```

---

I have attempted to get the sum of the column using `groupby` and `.sum()`:

```py
Total = df.groupby['MyColumn'].sum()
```

This causes  the following error:

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: For an illustration of why pandas is not pythonic, look no further than the confusion over how to simply sum a column.

Answer (score 395, accepted):

You should use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
Total = df['MyColumn'].sum()
print(Total)
319
```

Then you use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `Series`, in that case the index should be set as the same as the specific column you need to sum:

```
df.loc['Total'] = pd.Series(df['MyColumn'].sum(), index=['MyColumn'])
print(df)
         X  MyColumn      Y      Z
0        A      84.0   13.0   69.0
1        B      76.0   77.0  127.0
2        C      28.0   69.0   16.0
3        D      28.0   28.0   31.0
4        E      19.0   20.0   85.0
5        F      84.0  193.0   70.0
Total  NaN     319.0    NaN    NaN
```

because if you pass scalar, the values of all rows will be filled:

```
df.loc['Total'] = df['MyColumn'].sum()
print(df)
         X  MyColumn      Y      Z
0        A        84   13.0   69.0
1        B        76   77.0  127.0
2        C        28   69.0   16.0
3        D        28   28.0   31.0
4        E        19   20.0   85.0
5        F        84  193.0   70.0
Total  319       319  319.0  319.0
```

Two other solutions are with [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html), and [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) see the applications below:

```
df.at['Total', 'MyColumn'] = df['MyColumn'].sum()
print(df)
         X  MyColumn      Y      Z
0        A      84.0   13.0   69.0
1        B      76.0   77.0  127.0
2        C      28.0   69.0   16.0
3        D      28.0   28.0   31.0
4        E      19.0   20.0   85.0
5        F      84.0  193.0   70.0
Total  NaN     319.0    NaN    NaN
```

---

```
df.ix['Total', 'MyColumn'] = df['MyColumn'].sum()
print(df)
         X  MyColumn      Y      Z
0        A      84.0   13.0   69.0
1        B      76.0   77.0  127.0
2        C      28.0   69.0   16.0
3        D      28.0   28.0   31.0
4        E      19.0   20.0   85.0
5        F      84.0  193.0   70.0
Total  NaN     319.0    NaN    NaN
```

**Note:** Since Pandas v0.20, `ix` has been deprecated. Use `loc` or `iloc` instead.

Comment: That's great :) Thanks for the explanation, may I ask what `.loc` does in the above example?

Comment: `loc` is for [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement).

Comment: `at` works for setting with enlargement too, see last edit.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any preferred method?

Comment: Hmmm, docs says `The .loc/.ix/[] operations can perform enlargement when setting a non-existant key for that axis.`, so `loc` or `ix` or `[]`. in next [section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting) is writes `at may enlarge the object in-place as above if the indexer is missing.` So all methods are good, but `at` is fastest I think.

Comment: This is great. Is it possible to put "Total" in column X by modifying *df.loc['Total'] = df['MyColumn'].sum()*

Comment: What's the equivalent of df['col'].sum() in pyspark ?

Answer (score 42):

Another option you can go with here:

```
df.loc["Total", "MyColumn"] = df.MyColumn.sum()

#         X  MyColumn      Y       Z
#0        A     84.0    13.0    69.0
#1        B     76.0    77.0   127.0
#2        C     28.0    69.0    16.0
#3        D     28.0    28.0    31.0
#4        E     19.0    20.0    85.0
#5        F     84.0   193.0    70.0
#Total  NaN    319.0     NaN     NaN
```

---

You can also use `append()` method:

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(df.MyColumn.sum(), index = ["Total"], columns=["MyColumn"]))
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

In case you need to append sum for all **numeric** columns, you can do one of the followings:

Use `append` to do this in a functional manner (doesn't change the original data frame):

```
# select numeric columns and calculate the sums
sums = df.select_dtypes(pd.np.number).sum().rename('total')

# append sums to the data frame
df.append(sums)
#         X  MyColumn      Y      Z
#0        A      84.0   13.0   69.0
#1        B      76.0   77.0  127.0
#2        C      28.0   69.0   16.0
#3        D      28.0   28.0   31.0
#4        E      19.0   20.0   85.0
#5        F      84.0  193.0   70.0
#total  NaN     319.0  400.0  398.0
```

Use `loc` to mutate data frame in place:

```
df.loc['total'] = df.select_dtypes(pd.np.number).sum()
df
#         X  MyColumn      Y      Z
#0        A      84.0   13.0   69.0
#1        B      76.0   77.0  127.0
#2        C      28.0   69.0   16.0
#3        D      28.0   28.0   31.0
#4        E      19.0   20.0   85.0
#5        F      84.0  193.0   70.0
#total  NaN     638.0  800.0  796.0
```

Comment: How about the sum of all columns?

Comment: 1.st exampe: `FutureWarning: The pandas.np module is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import numpy directly instead`

Comment: How to plot this as a % on bar chart?

Comment: this solution works well for me thanks. How do I select certain columns to compute totals ?

Answer (score 12):

Similar to getting the length of a dataframe, `len(df)`, the following worked for pandas and blaze:

```
Total = sum(df['MyColumn'])
```

or alternatively

```
Total = sum(df.MyColumn)
print Total
```

Answer (score 5):

> There are two ways to sum of a column
>
> dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
>
> 1: sum(dataset.Column_name)
>
> 2: dataset['Column_Name'].sum()

If there is any issue in this the please correct me..

Answer (score 2):

As other option, you can do something like below

```
Group   Valuation   amount
    0   BKB Tube    156
    1   BKB Tube    143
    2   BKB Tube    67
    3   BAC Tube    176
    4   BAC Tube    39
    5   JDK Tube    75
    6   JDK Tube    35
    7   JDK Tube    155
    8   ETH Tube    38
    9   ETH Tube    56
```

Below script, you can use for above data

```
import pandas as pd    
data = pd.read_csv("daata1.csv")
bytreatment = data.groupby('Group')
bytreatment['amount'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Total of multiple columns

You can select the columns you want the total of and call `sum()` on them. To add a new row, use `loc[]`.

```py
df.loc['Total'] = df[['Y', 'Z']].sum()
```

Using the example in the OP, it makes the following transformation (note the new added row):

[image: result]

---

### Python's built-in `sum` vs pandas's `sum` method

For a single column, we can sum in two ways: use Python's built-in `sum()` function and use pandas' `sum()` method. It should be noted that pandas' method is optimized and much faster than Python's `sum()`. For example, to sum values in a column with 1mil rows, pandas' sum method is ~160 times faster than Python's built-in `sum()` function.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': range(1000000)})

%timeit a = df['Y'].sum()
# 1 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit b = sum(df['Y'])
# 160 ms ± 6.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So use pandas' methods wherever possible.