# sum set values in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Iam trying to sum a column inside a dataFrame that is a set of int.

something like : ['xxxx',{1,2,3}] and i need ['xxxx',6]

Thanks for your help.

```py
 for index,row in df_clusters.iterrows():
        if isinstance(row['sum_coefs'],set):
            row.loc['sum_coefs']=sum(row['sum_coefs'])
```

I got at the output an unchanged Dataframe with a set in my sum_coefs column and not the sum.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your `DataFrame`. Also, in general storing lists in a DataFrame (and in this case a list with a set) is not a good idea.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286569/get-total-of-pandas-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could try using [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
# Setup    
df_clusters = pd.DataFrame(['xxxx',set([1,2,3])], columns=['sum_coefs'])

def sum_sets(val):
    if isinstance(val, set):
        return sum(val)
    return val

df_clusters['sum_coefs'] = df_clusters['sum_coefs'].apply(sum_sets)
```

[out]

```
0    xxxx
1       6
dtype: object
```

---

Or alternatively, using an inline `lambda` function to achieve the same result:

```
df_clusters['sum_coefs'] = df_clusters['sum_coefs'].apply(lambda x: sum(x) if isinstance(x, set) else x)
```