# Sum values of a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum all values of a column. My df looks like this:

```
    Datum Uhrzeit Deutschland/Luxemburg[Euro/MWh]
0   06.06.2020   00:00                            7.69
1   06.06.2020   01:00                            1.46
2   06.06.2020   02:00                           -0.09
3   06.06.2020   03:00                            0.03
4   06.06.2020   04:00                            1.44
```

I have tried with a for loop:

```
for i in df["Deutschland/Luxemburg[Euro/MWh]"]:
    print(df["Deutschland/Luxemburg[Euro/MWh]"][i])
```

How could I do it right?

Comment: `df["Deutschland/Luxemburg[Euro/MWh]"].sum()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get total of Pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286569/get-total-of-pandas-column)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the sum function of pandas

`df.sum()`

I guess you want the sum of the last column, so you could do:

```
df['Deutschland/Luxemburg[Euro/MWh]'].sum()
```