# How to create this dataframe using Pandas?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, datatables

Please see this -

[image]

I want to create a table similar to this using pandas in python? Can anyone guide? Unable to understand how to add "Total Marks" text corresponding to two columns ("Student id" & "Course id").

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Data frame creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562479/python-pandas-data-frame-creation)

Comment: You can't have a value span over more than one column. "Total Marks" is just a stat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, pandas doesn't really support merged cells/cells spanning multiple rows in the same way as Excel/HTML do. A pandas-esque way to include the total row for a single column would be something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Student ID', 'Course ID', 'Marks']
data = [(103, 201, 67), (103, 203, 67), (103, 204, 89)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.at['Total marks', 'Marks'] = df['Marks'].sum()

print(df)
```

(per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286607/17568469))

This gives you:

```
                Student ID  Course ID  Marks
0                    103.0      201.0   67.0
1                    103.0      203.0   67.0
2                    103.0      204.0   89.0
Total marks            NaN        NaN  223.0
```

For HTML output like the image you provided, it looks like you would have to edit the HTML after exporting from pandas ([this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533330/pandas-data-frame-how-to-merge-columns) talks about columns but I believe the same applies for merging cells in rows).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wish to export your dataframe (df) with merged cells into excel, then try this code;

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\pandas_excel_export.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
# Edit below code if required (coloring, bold etc.)
merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': 1,
    'border': 1,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'fg_color': 'yellow'})
worksheet.merge_range('B5:C5', 'Total Marks', merge_format)
writer.save()
```

Hope this Helps...